# rails 3 - delete all related records to user - prevent orpahn data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've a simple blog style system where a user can have many entries.

I've tried to delete all of a users entries by doing the following -

```
user = User.find_by_id(1)
user.entries.delete_all
```

This hasn't succeeded in deleting the related entries, it has just set the user_id in that entry to nil -

```
<Entry id: 20, content: "test", user_id: nil, created_at: "2011-10-31 10:26:18", updated_at: "2011-10-31 10:26:18", attachment_id: nil, likes_count: nil, comments_count: nil>
```

A few questions, if you don't mind -

How can I ensure that all entries with no owner are deleted, and that their related info is deleted also? Based on the example above - I'd like to **remove the entry and it's related comments**

How should I have **initially avoided this problem**? I presume my user.entries.delete_all command was the wrong thing to do.

Comment: i'd move the backup part of your question to a new thread/question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you know the difference between `destroy` and `delete` in Rails? if you use `destroy` Rails will instantiate the records to remove first, and call all callbacks associated with `destroy` (before, after, around and cascading to associations). you could therefore create a `after_destroy` callback which destroys all user related data, entries etc. or you declare your has_many relationship with `:dependent => :destroy`, which automatically adds a callback to destroy all related items